# Remove trailing slash from permalinks except categories (WP)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just migrated my static website onto WordPress and previously did not use trailing slashes at the end of permalinks except when it's a category. WP adds the trailing slash by default and I'm struggling to achieve the set-up I had before.

**Here is what I tried so far:**

1. Removed the trailing slash in the backend under `Settings > Permalinks`. It works as expected except that it also removes the trailing slash when it's a category
2. The code below didn't work for me

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. The code below also didn't work for me

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   RewriteRule (.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Any other ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: It seems to me you're trying to work against WordPress here... Why do you want to remove these trailing slashes?

Comment: Because I had this structure in my static site which has some good rankings and ideally I don't want to change it now that I'm on WP